# Question about lesbesgue functions

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I am considering the measure space $([0,1),\mathcal{B}([0,1),\lambda)$ and for every whole number $n\geq1$ I have the function:

$u_{n}=nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^{n}$ , $x \in [0,1)$

I am asked the following:

a) show that $u_{n} \in \mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1),\lambda))$

b) find $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{[0,1)}u_{n}(x)d\lambda(x)$

I have done the following (referring to the theorems in my book):

a) Since $u_{n}$ is continuous then it is measurable and Riemann integrable. Since it is measurable Riemann integrable then it is Lebesgue integrable and therefore $u_{n} \in \mathcal{L}^{1}([0,1),\lambda))$ and we have that $\int_{[a,b]}ud\lambda =(R)\int_{a}^{b}u(x)dx$.

b) Using the last part of a) we have:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_{[0,1)}u_{n}(x)d\lambda(x)= \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(R)\int_{0}^{1} (nx^{n-1}-(n+1)x^{n})dx \\
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0 = 0$

Are a) and b) correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be more carefull.

Riemman integrability   is certainly valid for continuous functions on closed bounded intervals.

But there are continuous functions on $[0,1)$ that are not Riemman integrable, like $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$

But in this case the functions Riemman integrable since they are bounded and you can extend them continuously to $1$

So the Riemman integral 0f $_n$ will be equal to the Lebesgue integral

The rest is correct.